# Using formulas in the conditional format function in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to use the formula function in the conditional format, in excel,here's what I would like to do:

Conditional format Cell I11 using the formula function so that, Cell I11 looks at cell T11, if the value in T11 is greater than 60 but less than 70 then cell I11 will be highlighted in orange.

I can't seem to get it to work,any help or suggestions would be appreciated?

(Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post an image of it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula in Cell `I11` Conditional Foramt:

```
=AND(T10>60,T11<70)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I have a value in I11 that is 12:00(h,mm) that I want to conditional format with reference to T11,T11 is a whole number in this case 65.0,So currently I have one conditional format on cell I11 using the standard condition format(formula function) Rule formula:T11>70(then I11 will highlight red will red fill),this works if value in T11 is > 70.  I then created a second rule using your suggested formula: AND(T11>60,T11<70)(with cell I11 changing to orange colour font),but Cell I11  has remained unchanged with a cell value of T11 = 65. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but you did put the `=` sign in, right?

Comment: on the formatting window is has "use formula to determine which cell to format" and the following formula is displayed in the window below this, ="AND(T11>60,T11<70)" and just tried an additional = sign with no effect ="=AND(T11>60,T11<70)"

Comment: Sorry Chris for some reason my excel automatically putting in " marks,took them out and formula works fine!Thanks for you help,greatly appreciated!!